# Idiom Request: you know how to convince me

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

Do you know any idioms meaning "you know how to convince me"?

Edit: the context is a humorous response to someone offers you something you can't resist

Comment: You've talked me into it.

Comment: What is the context for and the meaning behind this idiom you’re looking for?   I immediately thought it would be “someone asking you to do something and you hinting at what you need from them first.” but others have offered options for  “utterances of acquiescence”, or “utterances of praise”.

Comment: @Jim updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Common in UK is:
"OK, you twisted my arm"

It's said sarcastically, as no arm-twisting was really required.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom ***[silver-tongued](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/silver-tongued)*** generally refers to someone perceived to have great powers of persuasion.

> sil·ver-tongued (sĭl′vər-tŭngd′)
>
> adj.
>
> Having or exhibiting the power of fluent and persuasive speech; eloquent.

It is often used - most often in the second person- in the highly idiomatic and humourously applied phrase **silver-tongued devil**, e.g. "You've talked me into it, you silver-tonged devil, you!"

Comment: I guess **"Oh, you little devil."** is short for that.

Answer (score 0):

To ***[bring somebody around](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bring-around-round):***

> to manage to persuade someone to do something or to agree with you.
>
> - I’m sure I can bring him around to our point of view.

(Longman Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

**'You have the gift of the gab.'**

The 'gift of the gab' is the 'the ability to speak easily and confidently in a way that makes people want to listen to you and believe you'.

> http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gift-of-the-gab

**'You have the power of persuasion.'**

The 'power of persuasion' is simply that - the ability to persuade people to do something.

> http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gift-of-the-gab

Answer (score 0):

"**You could sell sand to the Arabs.**"

"**You could sell ice to an Eskimo.**"

Transparent enough adages about someone's powers of persuasion.

> "He could sell snow to Eskimos" or "He could sell sand to the Arabs."
>   both of which mean "He is extremely persuasive"

[[PaulQ; Wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-proverb-or-a-saying-representing-this-meaning.3243107/)]

Answer (score 0):

> "Sold!"
>
> "You've got yourself a deal!"
>
> "You had me at [first part of a multi-part proposition]!"
>
> "How can I say no to that?"
>
> "You read my mind."

This is what I hear most commonly.